# Is the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{[x]}}{[x]}$ a one sided limit or not?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{[x]}}{[x]}$ a one sided limit or not? Here $[\, \cdot\, ]$ is the greatest integer function.

According to me the right hand limit will be not defined and the left hand limit will be $\dfrac{-\sin1}{-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're completely correct.

The function is undefined for $0<x<1$, so the limit from the right is meaningless.

On the other hand the function is continuous (and constant) in the interval $(-1,0)$, so the limit from the left exists and is $\sin1$.